# Using Handlebars with Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, handlebars.js

I am learning Backbone/Handlebars/Require. I have looked all over online and on SO - are there any tutorials or websites that you can direct me to that would provide helpful information for using using handlebars instead of underscore?

Comment: The best place for documentation is the Handlebars website, which you can find at http://handlebarsjs.com. In regards to using Handlebars with Backbone, there is no difference or extra complexity involved. The only difference is that you have to include Handlebars, but other than that it is similar to using Underscore as your template engine. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Do we still have to include underscore, or can that be done away with?

Comment: Yes. Underscore is a dependency for Backbone as it heavily relies on it.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Using `handlebars.js` instead of `underscore` templating is pretty straightforward. Check out this example:

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/backbone.js/tutorials/what-is-a-view
(scroll to the "Loading a Template" section)

```
SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        // Compile the template using underscore
        var template = _.template( $("#search_template").html(), {} );
        // Load the compiled HTML into the Backbone "el"
        this.el.html( template );
    }
});
```

Basically, the convention in backbone is to build your html in a render function. The use of templating engine is left completely up to you (which I like about Backbone). So you'd just change it to:

```
SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        this.render();
    },
    render: function(){
        // Compile the template using Handlebars
        var template = Handlebars.compile( $("#search_template").html() );
        // Load the compiled HTML into the Backbone "el"
        this.el.html( template );
    }
});
```

Since you're using `require.js`, you can make `Handlebars` a dependency at the top of your module. I'm pretty new to this, but it sounds like the learning to focus on would be `Backbone.js` patterns and `require.js` usage.

Comment: if you prefer to keep your templates in separate files, how would you load them? I am thinking sammy.js style, where you could specify the address of a template file in it's `render`-method?

Comment: When using `Backbone.Model` or `Backbone.Collection` as the template context, remember to use [`.toJSON()`](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON)

Comment: This is not that simple if you already developed a application using underscore as a template engine. Underscore lets you write JavaScript code inside a template (off course you got to use special tags), but Handlebars doesn't.

Comment: Yes, @RaviHamsa, migration would be a different challenge because the templating languages have different capabilities. If you want to switch, suggest you just write all new templates in Handlebars until you reach a critical mass, then migrate old stuff in a refactoring work effort.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer to compile the template once (during initialize), that way you avoid to recompile the template with every render. Also, you need to pass the model to the compilated template in order to generate the HTML:

```
SearchView = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function(){
    // Compile the template just once
    this.template = Handlebars.compile($("#search_template").html());
    this.render();
  },
  render: function(){
    // Render the HTML from the template
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using require.js you wont be able to use the current Handlebars file. I used the following [Handlebars Plugin](https://github.com/SlexAxton/require-handlebars-plugin) and it seems to be kept up to date with the current version. Just replace your Handlebars file with the plugin above if Handlebars is returning null in your module.

Answer (score 0):

```
define(["app", "handlebars",
    "text!apps/templates/menu.tpl"
], function (app, Handlebars, template) {

    return {
        index: Marionette.ItemView.extend({
            template: Handlebars.compile(template),
            events: {
                'click .admin-menu-ref': 'goToMenuItem'
            },
            goToMenuItem: function (e) {
               //......
            }
        })
    }
});


 new view.index({model: models});
```