# Replace underscore with handlebars

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js, handlebars.js

I used to use the handlebars and now began to study backbone.js, but read that the backbone does not work without underscore. I tried to find the answer to this question , but unfortunately to no avail. Is it possible to completely substitute the underscore for handlebars in backbone? Thanks!

Comment: No. "Backbone's only hard dependency is Underscore.js ( >= 1.7.0)." - http://backbonejs.org/

Comment: It's sad for me. Thank you!

Comment: Underscore and handlebars are two very different animals. One is a utility library, the other is a templating system. It's not clear what you mean by when you say replace one with the other. The only point of overlap is that underscore provides a minimalistic templating system, but you are free to use any templating system you want in Backbone.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to completely substitute the underscore for handlebars in backbone?

No. You can't remove Underscore. However, you *can* use Handlebars as a template system for Backbone.

Here's a StackOverflow answer that goes over the basics:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10843963/2793460

Comment: I know how to use handlebars with backbone. The question is about possibility to replace them.

Comment: Ok. I wasn't sure how familiar you were based on your question. But the answer is still no, because Underscore is a dependency for Backbone.

Comment: I prefer handlebars templates over underscore. Its kept my templates very logic-less, and simpler. I use it with backbone and I especially don't mind the extra library now that I use handlebars.runtime which is small. Its all bundled together anyway in my build process.