# Handlebars with Backbone template not rendering

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I have an app which uses both Backbone and Handlebars on a server and a client.

## Server

Backbone and Express-Handlebars installed

**app.js**

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'));
app.engine('.hbs', expHbs({
  defaultLayout: 'index', 
  extname: '.hbs'
}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
```

**index.js**

```
exports.init = function(req, res){
  res.render('contact/index');
};
```

**index.hbs**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>Send A Message</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="contact"></div>
  </div>
  ....some code

<script id="tmpl-contact" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <form>

      bootstrap with handlebars temlates {{....}} in here

  </form>
</script>
```

## Client

On the client I have Backbone and Handlebars installed via Bower

In **index.js** Backbone.view

```
var Handlebars = require('handlebars');
  app.ContactView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#contact',
    template: Handlebars.compile( $('#tmpl-contact').html() ),
    events: {
      'submit form': 'preventSubmit',
      'click .btn-contact': 'contact'
   },
    initialize: function() {
      this.model = new app.Contact();
      this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync', this.render);
      this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
      this.$el.html(this.template( this.model.attributes ));
      this.$el.find('[name="name"]').focus();
   },
    preventSubmit: function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
   },
    contact: function() {
      this.$el.find('.btn-contact').attr('disabled', true);

      this.model.save({
        name: this.$el.find('[name="name"]').val(),
        email: this.$el.find('[name="email"]').val(),
        message: this.$el.find('[name="message"]').val()
      });
    }
  });
```

What happens is that index.hbs renders on the server-side normally, but it is not rendering a form inside script; it shows empty `<div id="contact"></div>` and doesn't shows any errors in console.

As shown here [Using Handlebars with Backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072324/using-handlebars-with-backbone), a way to replace underscore templating with handlebars is simply to replace `_.template` with `Handlebars.compile`, but neither of these options works for me. I also tried different **type** attributes for `<script>` and it's still not working.

How can I fix this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

### Added full index.js on client

```
/* global app:true */

var Handlebars = require('Нandlebars');

(function() {
  'use strict';

  app = app || {};

  app.Contact = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '/contact/',
    defaults: {
      success: false,
      errors: [],
      errfor: {},
      name: '',
      email: '',
      message: ''
    }
  });

  app.ContactView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#contact',
    template: Handlebars.compile( $('#tmpl-contact').html() ),
    events: {
      'submit form': 'preventSubmit',
      'click .btn-contact': 'contact'
    },
    initialize: function() {
      this.model = new app.Contact();
      this.listenTo(this.model, 'sync', this.render);
      this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
      this.$el.html(this.template( this.model.attributes ));
      this.$el.find('[name="name"]').focus();
    },
    preventSubmit: function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
    },
    contact: function() {
      this.$el.find('.btn-contact').attr('disabled', true);

      this.model.save({
        name: this.$el.find('[name="name"]').val(),
        email: this.$el.find('[name="email"]').val(),
        message: this.$el.find('[name="message"]').val()
          });
        }
     });

  $(document).ready(function() {
    app.contactView = new app.ContactView();
  });
}());
```

Comment: Where are you initializing the view in `index.js`...? It is not enough to declare a view. You need to initialize it after the required stuff in loaded.

Comment: @T J If you mean using Backbone.Model.Extend, I have it it a same file

Comment: (function() {
      'use strict';

      app = app || {};

      app.Contact = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url: '/contact/',
        defaults: {
          success: false,
          errors: [],
          errfor: {},
          name: '',
          email: '',
          message: ''
        }
      });

it was a https://github.com/jedireza/drywall with Jade and Underscore templates. I'm trying to change it to Handlebars.

Comment: Based on the tests I did, though unorthodox, your access to the templates should work as you have it. So, I suspect the issue is in your client-side code. I would be debugging the render function in your ContactView, and you could try replacing your form with a simple piece of text to more easily isolate the problem. Please share what additional info you determine.

Comment: No, you should have `new app.ContactView()` somewhere. BTW if you're sharing code blocks please [edit] and add it in question. They are unreadable in comments

Comment: @rasmeister What I was trying to do is to add to my existing app running on express with express-handlebars with jquery some functionality from Drywall which is also running on express so I "merged" a routes and try making handlebars wok both on a server and a client. So I think It renders now all the server side elements and not the client. The repo is here https://bitbucket.org/as500966/adminpanel/src the server side is in **views**, client goes minfied **scripts** folder. Mb you know what are best integration practices , maybe even some global changes that can be more effective. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need the server side render for SEO? Thanks for the repo... will have a look.

Comment: @rasmeister Actually didn't thought about SEO for now. I'm pretty new in programming it's my first project so the purpose is to try making things work both on client and server side.  @T J thanks for advise, added a full client side file

Comment: `$(document).ready(function() {
    app.contactView = new app.ContactView();
  });` will initialize the view then your app loads. Is the content of `index.hbs` available at that point? or is it loaded later?

Comment: @T J I'm not sure. All public js files are minified and concatinated into main.min.js which is loaded in main server-side expHbs layout after {{{ body }}}, so probably  the content of index.hbs must be available before ContactView initialisation. Do you think a problem is in there?

Comment: The best way to solve your problem right now would be to try and create a [mcve]. Placing `console.log` at strategic points within the code to ensure everything is loaded and available when needed will help you pinpoint where the problem is coming.

Comment: [1] I still can't get this work. For now I disabled all auth strategies and routes beside the front-end. Changed vendor libs from build to cdn. Removed all the Backbone code and template script from the hbs file. So i tried to create an empty backbone object `var Something = Backbone.Model.Extend ({});` it returned me `Uncaught TypeError: Backbone.Model.Extend is not a function` athough cdn libs are loaded as required.

Comment: [2] The page without any js retuns `Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined` to signup file in the line `app = app || {};` which actually must prevent it. During the changes I tried to change the order of loading static, templates and routes in app.js and still got the same errors. Maybe the whole app is not woking and it worth to reinstall everything?

Comment: How is `index.js` loaded in client? is it part of `index.hbs`? If not, are you sure it is loaded after `index.hbs` is rendered in browser?

Comment: @T J It's a separate file miified and concatinated with others into `main.min.js`. `index.hbs` renders everything passed to him in the `{{{body}}}`. `main.min.js` is required after the `{{{body}}}` element, so it must be loaded after the DOM. I think the problem that there are 2 instanses of handlebars and the page is rendered twice. I need somehow live 1 instance

Answer (score 1):

So as mentioned here `Handlebars.compile` must load after handlebars template in `<script></script>` is loaded into the DOM. In this case when using express-hanldebars, a link to js file must be placed after `{{{ body }}}` element in the main layout. That is the right answer.

There is one more problem here that `app` can't be defined globally as it appears in **index.js**

In order to define `app` globally you have to move `app = app || {};` outside the IIFE scope and put it at the beginning of a file and declare it as a global variable: `var app = app || {};`. If there are multiple backbone files they should all implement a similar structure in order to `app` be global.