# Is there any way to render Handlebars templates on server via Backbone in front-end?

Tags: templates, backbone.js, handlebars.js

### edited

This question is in addition to previous [Handlebars with Backbone template not rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42335681/handlebars-with-backbone-template-not-rendering) problem in which browseser was not rendering forms at all now the problem was solved for the form but returns another error which is possibly also with the rendering.

---

I have an app with Backbone on front-end and Express in back-end with express-handlebars templates and I was trying to change from Underscore templating to Handlebars while still leaving backbone logic behind. So the way I did it - installing handlebars via Bower and then required it.

```
  app.ContactView = Backbone.View.extend({
     //....
    template: Handlebars.compile( $('#tmpl-contact').html() ),
     //....
  });
```

instead of

```
  app.ContactView = Backbone.View.extend({
     //....
    template: _.template( $('#tmpl-contact').html() ),
     //....
  });
```

But it returns errors and I don't really get what causes them.

When I try to load a page, for example:

```
http://192.168.33.10:3000/contact/
```

It doesn't shows any errors in the browser. But if I move to:

```
http://192.168.33.10:3000/about
```

which doesn't even have Backbone logic behind it returns an error:

> You must pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars.compile. You
>   passed undefined

Which means that template is compiled before the DOM loads on the page. But my Backbone script is loading after html script e. g. after the `{{{body}}}` element. Also if there is a problem with an order I should get this error on every, not only when moving to another.

So I think the cause is some kind of a conflict between front-end handlebars and express-handlebars on a server. How to solve this, preferably that templates to be rendered via `expHbs` instance?

Comment: You have server side rendering as well as client side rendering? Your server side handlebars renders handlebar template for the client side?

Comment: @T J I have 2 instanses of handlebars running on a same app. It was previosley running on  ` expHbs ` on server and now it is running on ` Handlebars ` instanse, e.g. ` Handlebars.compile ` on the frony-end. This is related to my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42335681/handlebars-with-backbone-template-not-rendering and I disabled everything exept the **contact** view **home** and **about** views which does not have any backbone logic at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handlebars with Backbone template not rendering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42335681/handlebars-with-backbone-template-not-rendering)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by loading each Backbone part as a separate file for its route.

Answer (score 0):

If the only change that you made was:

```
template: Handlebars.compile( $('#tmpl-contact').html() ),
```

to:

```
template: _.template( $('#tmpl-contact').html() ),
```

it wouldn't cause the problems you're describing.  As the error message told you "You passed undefined", and `undefined` wouldn't have worked with the Underscore code either.

It seems more likely that you changed something else, and that change caused the issue you described. However, without more code (ideally a JS Fiddle) it's hard to say what.

Comment: This should be a comment... and I don't think it's possible to demonstrate server side handlebars rendering in a fiddle..?

Comment: @machinegoast Please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42335681/handlebars-with-backbone-template-not-rendering. It's a same code, but now it doesn't shows any errors on a particularly view only when getting to another view.